# How can i stop Radlistview from reloading the list when i navigate back to the page

Tags: javascript, nativescript

i have a page with a form in it, the form data is then passed on to the next page which displays the respective items from a database. everything works fine, when i click on an item, it takes me to another page as expected. but when i go back to the page with the list items, it reloads the list. How can i stop that, i want the users to be go back and continue scrolling from where they stopped like instagram explore page.

```
exports.pageLoaded = function (args) {
    const page = args.object;
    const searchViewModel = new SearchViewModel();
    page.bindingContext = searchViewModel;
    searchViewModel.initDataItems();
    searchViewModel.addMoreItemsFromSource(8);
}
```

**The issue**

i think the issue is because i used `const searchViewModel = new SearchViewModel();` in pageLoaded function but i dont have an alternative for that, i did that because of the previous page that is sending data to the page that displays the list. if i don't do that it wont reload the list when the user searches.

**My Aim**

What i want is for the page to load new items when the user searches, and then when the user clicks on an item and goes back to the list, it shouldn't reload the list but continue.

**My question**

How can i navigate to another page `onItemTap` without deleting the items on the listview. or which page even can i use that will only fire the first time the page was opened

**Playground sample**

[Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=pVNQHr&v=26)

Comment: You could simply remove page load event after first call or with a simple if create binding context only if it's not already created.

Answer (score 1):

i have found a solution, using **[modal pages](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/modal-view#modal-view)**

Your item tap will open a modal page, therefore the listview items still remain. so the code will be:

```
const modalViewModule = "image/image";

    exports.onImageTap = function (args) {
      const view = args.view;
      // const page = view.page;
      const tappedItem = view.bindingContext;
      const mainView = args.object;
      const option = {
        context: tappedItem,
        fullscreen: true,
      };
      mainView.showModal(modalViewModule, option);
    }
```

and then the modal page you're opening will be

```
<Page shownModally="onShownModally">
    <!-- Your page content -->
</Page>
```

[My playground sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=pVNQHr&v=58)